# Seeding the mobile app designer (MAD) 12C cache

Tags: android, oracle, caching, business-intelligence, obiee

I'm new to Oracle mobile app designer (MAD)12c.
As you know, it has cache feature. 
I have some questions about MAD cache.

1- where and how dose it save or store? Means dose it store like bi server cache or bi presentation server cache in files or is stored in another way?

2-how can I seed it? For example for seeding bi server cache there are some different ways like using agents.So in which way I can seed MAD cache? Is there any odbc or another function, command, feature similar to agent etc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which cache are you talking about? Which "MAD 12c cache"??

Comment: The cache which there is in MAD module and we can enable it through app properties in the upper right corner of mobile app designer workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the only information which exists is the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e40220.pdf

Check 7.4 - Setting App Caching Properties

Comment: Thanks Mr Chris for your answer. I've used this feature before. In other word, I'm using it in my app now. My question is exactly about this matter that is there any way to automate seeding this cache? Or the only way is open it on mobile device to seed purpose?

Comment: The latter. You can't "push" the cache to a mobile device.